# tmux %if %else %endif syntax misbehaving when using a String Comparison statement on a format variable invoked on .tmux.conf

Tags: linux, environment-variables, tmux, syntax

I am trying to achieve the functionality of be able to understand when a certain Window in 'tmux' is above or below 10.

So I have used the following on my `~/.tmux.conf`, which I am sourcing from different Windows within a tmux session.

```
%if '#{<:#{window_index},10}'
    display -p 'Window index is lower than 10'
%else
    display -p 'Window index is higher than 10'
%endif
```

I appended that to my .tmux.conf and source it from those different windows , and Is actually not behaving as expected.

Most of the Windows are throwing me a 'Window index is higher than 10' , expect Window index 1 for some reason. But I think this pattern is not consistent , as I am trying the same in other session and all of the Windows are throwing me the else statement.

Answer (score 2):

`<` and `>` within tmux perform a *string* comparison (sorting), character by character. The string `2` is indeed "greater" than `10` because the first character `2` > `1` (the rest of the string doesn't need to be compared).

Use the `e` operator for numeric operations:

```
#{e|<:#{window_index},10}
```

Comment: Thank you , we are getting closer. Still 
` %if '#{e|<:#{window_index},10}' display -p 'Window index is lower than 10' %else display -p 'Window index is higher than 10' %endif `
Is not working in my ~/.tmux.conf .
I think it may have to do with the execution environment of this format-variable (window_index) , maybe is not meant to be read on the config as a "static" read. (sorry for the formatting is not parsing my markdown)

Comment: Yeah, that's another reason; window_index only makes sense in situations that apply to a specific window, while the config as a whole is not window-specific. Keybinds or hooks or e.g. "status format" variables would have access to window parameters.